# @Before/@BeforeEach inheritance behaviour change JUnit4 / JUnit5

Tags: java, junit4, junit5

When migrating from JUnit4 to JUnit5 I found a change in the behaviour of JUnit4 and JUnit5 and wanted to check if the change was a bug in JUnit4 or in JUnit5 and how to do it correctly.

Lets assume the following structure:

One base class

```
public class BaseTestClass {

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        System.out.println("Base Test Class");
    }
}
```

Another class that inherits from this base class

```
public class InheritsFromBase extends BaseTestClass {

    @Override
    public void setUp() {
        System.out.println("I inherit from base");

        super.setUp();
    }
}
```

And an actual test class

```
public class ActualTests extends InheritsFromBase {

    @Test
    public void myTest(){
        Assert.assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

If I run `myTest()` in JUnit 4 then the `setUp()` method of both, `BaseTestClass` and `InheritsFromBase` is called.

After migrating this code to JUnit5, the `setUp()` methods are not called anymore. I had to manually add the `@BeforeEach` annotation on `InheritsFromBase`.

Resulting in the following classes:

```
public class BaseTestClass {

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp(){
        System.out.println("Base Test Class");
    }
}

public class InheritsFromBase extends BaseTestClass {

    @Override
    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        System.out.println("I inherit from base");

        super.setUp();
    }
}

public class ActualTests extends InheritsFromBase {

    @Test
    public void myTest(){
        Assertions.assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

So my question: Was the behaviour in JUnit4 correct or in JUnit5?

Comment: There is useful extension which check for such ignored JUnit 5 callback methods: [JUnit5MisusageCheck](https://github.com/cronn/test-utils#junit5misusagecheck)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The actual behavior for JUnit 5 is expected as the [@BeforeEach javadoc](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.1/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/BeforeEach.html)  states :

> **Inheritance**
>
> `@BeforeEach` methods are inherited from superclasses as long as they
> are not overridden.

You override the `setup()`  method that contains `@BeforeEach` in the `InheritsFromBase` class.
So it is not inherited any longer.

For JUnit 4, the [`@Before` javadoc](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.13/org/junit/Before.html) doesn't state any particularity and inheritance abilities.
So you should consider the actual behavior as "normal" but no documented.

To get the same behavior with JUnit 5, you should do the reverse what you do with JUni4 : remove `@BeforeEach` in the super class and add it only in the subclass.

```
public class BaseTestClass {

    public void setUp() {
        System.out.println("Base Test Class");
    }
}


public class InheritsFromBase extends BaseTestClass {

    @Override
    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        System.out.println("I inherit from base");
        super.setUp();
    }
}
```

As I execute the tests, it produces as output :

> I inherit from base
>
> Base Test Class