# @BeforeAll in superclass is not executed

Tags: junit, kotlin, junit5

In superclass, the method annotated with `@BeforeClass` seems not to be executed

```
    @TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
open class TestBase {

    var status: Boolean = false

    @BeforeAll
    open fun setStatus() {
        status = true
    }
}

class MyAppTest : TestBase() {

    @Test
    fun testStatus() {
        assertTrue(status) //fails
    }

}
```

Is this the desirable behaviour or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [@Before/@BeforeEach inheritance behaviour change JUnit4 / JUnit5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48864716/before-beforeeach-inheritance-behaviour-change-junit4-junit5)

Answer (score 6):

The [documentation](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.2/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/BeforeAll.html) explicitly states:

> `@BeforeAll` methods are inherited from superclasses as long as they are not *hidden* or *overridden*. Furthermore, `@BeforeAll` methods from superclasses will be executed before `@BeforeAll` methods in subclasses.

So this would not be the desired behavior. But since `setStatus()` is *open*, you have to be careful not to *override* it.